# How to fetch array using loops

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

'array(1) { ["entry"]=> array(14) { [0]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "actiontypedesc" [1]=> string(41) "Registration of ntsfilters.com for 1 year" } } [1]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "unutilisedsellingamount" [1]=> string(9) "-1531.770" } } [2]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "sellingamount" [1]=> string(9) "-**1531.770**" } } [3]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "entityid" [1]=> string(8) "57929388" } } [4]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "actionstatus" [1]=> string(7) "Success" } } [5]=> array(2) { ["string"]=> string(14) "privacydetails" ["hashtable"]=> array(1) { ["entry"]=> array(13) { [0]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "actiontypedesc" [1]=> string(64) "Purchase of Privacy Protection Service for domain ntsfilters.com" } } [1]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "unutilisedsellingamount" [1]=> string(5) "0.000" } } [2]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "sellingamount" [1]=> string(5) "**0.000**" } } [3]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "entityid" [1]=> string(8) "57929388" } } [4]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "actionstatus" [1]=> string(7) "Success" } } [5]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "status" [1]=> string(7) "Success" } } [6]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "eaqid" [1]=> string(9) "275211486" } } [7]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "customerid" [1]=> string(8) "11885341" } } [8]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "description" [1]=> string(14) "ntsfilters.com" } } [9]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "actiontype" [1]=> string(25) "PurchasePrivacyProtection" } } [10]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "invoiceid" [1]=> string(8) "47907905" } } [11]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(21) "sellingcurrencysymbol" [1]=> string(3) "PKR" } } [12]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "actionstatusdesc" [1]=> string(32) "Operation completed successfully" } } } } } [6]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "status" [1]=> string(7) "Success" } } [7]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "eaqid" [1]=> string(9) "275211481" } } [8]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "customerid" [1]=> string(8) "11885341" } } [9]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "description" [1]=> string(14) "ntsfilters.com" } } [10]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "actiontype" [1]=> string(12) "AddNewDomain" } } [11]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "invoiceid" [1]=> string(8) "47907904" } } [12]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(21) "sellingcurrencysymbol" [1]=> string(3) "PKR" } } [13]=> array(1) { ["string"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "actionstatusdesc" [1]=> string(42) "Domain registration completed Successfully" } } } }'

i have this array, and want to fetch only highlethed values. plz help

this is my output in the dump array, suppose  i want any specific value in a variable using loop. how it can be done

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_string($store_array);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,true);
//var_dump($array);
foreach($array as $key1 => $value){
 foreach($value as $info){
  foreach($info as $price){
   foreach($price as $price_new){
   echo $price_new;
   echo "<br/>";
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Which value do you want? And do you want only 1 value?

Comment: yes,
i want selling amount for each domain

Comment: @FarooqKhan Please edit your Question to show what you have tried so far and don't post code in a comment (Also add What you have, what you want and what you have tried so far)

Comment: i have dump the whole array which i get in response when a customer search for domain. now when i get response, i want to pick only amount from this array for each domain.

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($store_array);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,true);
//var_dump($array);
foreach($array as $key1 => $value){
 foreach($value as $info){
  foreach($info as $price){
   foreach($price as $price_new){
   echo $price_new;
   echo "<br/>";
   }
  }
 }
}`
this is what i have tried

Comment: @FarooqKhan Please edit your question! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27457483/edit

Comment: @FarooqKhan can you provide the structure of the code you are using so we can understand, and what you want to be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your Question, why don't you do some string comparison like:

```
foreach ($arrayName as $value) {
if($value === "some value"){
    echo "<p>Found variable</p>";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: plz provide me your skype ID, i want to talk plz